# Parallelize a function call with mpi4py

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I want to use mpi4py to parallize an optimization problem. To minimize my function I use the minimize routine from scipy

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x, data) :
    #returns f(x)
x = minimize(f, x0, args=(data))
```

Now if I want to parallelize my function using mpi4py. The implementatino of the minimization algorithm is sequential and can only run on one process so only my function is parallelized which is not a problem since the function call is to most time consuming step. But I can't figure out how to implement this problem, with parallel and sequential parts.

Here is my attempt:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = 100 # for testing
step = N//size # say that N is divisible by size
def mpi_f(x, data) :
    x0 = x[rank*step:(rank+1)*step]
    res = f(x0, data)
    res = comm.gather(res, root=0)
    if rank == 0 :
        return res

if rank == 0 :
   x = np.zeros(N)
   xs = minimize(mpi_f, x, args=(data))
```

This is obviously not working since mpi_f only runs on the process 0. So I am asking how should I proceed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In your code, the root process is the only one which calls `comm.gather()` since the root process is the only one which calls the parallelized cost function. Hence, the program faces a deadlock. You are well aware of this issue.

To overcome this deadlock, the other processes must call the cost function as many times as `minimize` needs it. Since this number of calls is not known in advance, a `while` loop seems suitable for these processes.

The stopping condition of the while loop is to be defined. This flag is to be brodcast from the root process to all processes since the root process is the only one aware of the fact that the `minimize()` function ended. The broadcast must be performed in the cost function, since all processes must test the end of the minimize function at each iteration. Since `minimize` makes use of the return value of the function, the flag is [passed by reference via a mutable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Finally, here is a potential solution to your problem. It is ran by `mpirun -np 4 python main.py`. I used `fmin()` instead of `minimize()` because my version of scipy is outdated.

```
#from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fmin
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = 100 # for testing
step = N//size # say that N is divisible by size

def parallel_function_caller(x,stopp):
    stopp[0]=comm.bcast(stopp[0], root=0)
    summ=0
    if stopp[0]==0:
        #your function here in parallel
        x=comm.bcast(x, root=0)
        array= np.arange(x[0]-N/2.+rank*step-42,x[0]-N/2.+(rank+1)*step-42,1.)
        summl=np.sum(np.square(array))
        summ=comm.reduce(summl,op=MPI.SUM, root=0)
        if rank==0:
            print "value is "+str(summ)
    return summ

if rank == 0 :
   stop=[0]
   x = np.zeros(1)
   x[0]=20
   #xs = minimize(parallel_function_caller, x, args=(stop))
   xs = fmin(parallel_function_caller,x0= x, args=(stop,))
   print "the argmin is "+str(xs)
   stop=[1]
   parallel_function_caller(x,stop)

else :
   stop=[0]
   x=np.zeros(1)
   while stop[0]==0:
      parallel_function_caller(x,stop)
```